# Drupal add google analytics event tracking query strings to url

Tags: 7, emails, google-analytics

I have Drupal 7 site for sending the newsletter. I am using [simplenews](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjds5jhlsXLAhULUo4KHdI_Cx8QFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fsimplenews&usg=AFQjCNFz-bK_CjBh8e5DujVJ7g4vZLNq_Q&sig2=y7AcWJY5Y5DEf7lv_z2imA&bvm=bv.116954456,d.c2E) module for sending newsletter. I want to add google analytics tracking query strings to all links in the newsletter so that it is tracked in my google analytics account. How can I achieve this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your links [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867) and add them in your newsletter node content and/or mail template.

Comment: Where can I find this url or campaign in google analytics